# Reputation calculation / display bug

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

A couple of days ago I only got 10 rep for an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786701/1786728#1786728) (which now that I think about it, could be moved to superuser :) ) on stackoverflow with 1 upvote. My rep went from 201 to 211.

No Questions and the only Community Wiki answer is "How can I help my poor friend learning to program?" with 2 upvotes.

My current rep should be 236 (16 upvotes + 5 accepted answers + startrep(1)) instead of 221. The reputation chart seems to show the right reputation.

The bug appeared about 48 hours ago. I went through the faq and meta.stackoverflow and couldn't find an explanation for the missing 15 points except for the daily repcap that I did not exceed.

**Edit:**
The solution to the Problem was a rep recalc. Why the bug appeared is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Here is an image of my current reputation: http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/2558/repbug.jpg

Comment: Want me to risk a rep recalc?

Comment: there is a risk? but feel free :)

Comment: Yes; if you have rep from questions that have been deleted / migrated it can be lost; and a few other such scenarios. Sometimes people have lost 300+ points during a rep recalc. You gained ;-p

Comment: The rep recalc seems to have worked. thx. I'll add a note to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rep recalc done; you're now 236 - all is well again ;-p

Answer (score 1):

```
 160     16 upvotes (community wiki doesn't count)
  75     5 accepted answers
   1     starting rep
----- +
 236
```

Looks like you're missing 15 rep indeed. :)

Sue Stack Overflow and get rich!

Comment: its 18 with community wiki. and even with 5 reputation for free I would have postet this question. It just bugs me :D

Comment: @marg: Hrmm, right!

Comment: If you sue SO, do you get paid in reputation?